# How to move a white space in a string?

Tags: python, string, whitespace

I need to move a whitespace in a string one position to the right.
This is my code:

```
for i in range(0,len(resultaat)):
    if resultaat[i] == " ":
        string = resultaat[:i] + resultaat[i+1] + " " + resultaat[i+2:]
```

E.g.:
If resultaat =

```
"TH EZE NO  FPYTHON."
```

Than my output needs to be:

```
'THE ZEN OF PYTHON.'
```

, but the output that I get is:

```
"TH EZE NO F PYTHON."
```

I think this happened because the loop undid the action where it moved the previous space.
I don't know how to fix this problem.
Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: is your resultaat a typo? there are 2 spaces in between the "NO" and "FPYTHON."

Answer (score 2):

Each time through the loop you're getting slices of the original `resultaat` string, without the changes you've made for previous iterations.

You should copy `resultaat` to `string` first, then use that as the source of each slice so you accumulate all the changes.

```
string = resultaat
for i in range(0,len(resultaat)):
    if resultaat[i] == " ":
        string = string[:i] + string[i+1] + " " + string[i+2:]
```

Comment: Additional hint: You shouldn't name a variable `string`, because [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) is the name of a Python module.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
# first get the indexes that the character you want to merge
indexes = [i for i, c in enumerate(resultaat) if c == ' ']
for i in indexes: # go through those indexes and swap the characters as you have done
    resultaat = resultaat[:i] + resultaat[i+1] + " " + resultaat[i+2:] # updating resultaat each time you want to swap characters
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the stated input value actually has one more space than is actually needed then:

```
TXT = "TH EZE NO FPYTHON."

def process(s):
    t = list(s)
    for i, c in enumerate(t[:-1]):
        if c == ' ':
            t[i+1], t[i] = ' ', t[i+1]
    return ''.join(t)

print(process(TXT))
```

**Output:**

```
THE ZEN OF PYTHON.
```